# Change command to one that does not fork and use up resources

Tags: linux, file-io, command-line, fedora

I have the following command which deletes files that are one day old and that are of mp3 file type.

```
find /home/get/public_html/audio -daystart -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1 
-type f -name "*.mp3" |xargs rm -f
```

The problem with this is when I run it, it sometimes says,

> "fork": resource xargs not available.

Does this mean this command first finds the file and then starts many process to delete each file?

How can I (when a file is found) immediately delete it rather than it being piped to xargs?

<sup>I can't use that `-delete` ("invalid predicate").</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about trying:

```
 find /home/get/public_html/audio -daystart -maxdepth 1 -mtime +1 
    -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your man page for find, it might support -delete, making it as simple as

```
find /home/get/public_html/audio -daystart -maxdepth 1 \
   -mtime +1 -type f -name "*.mp3" -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the "-delete" flag to find, instead of piping to xargs?